# use of or not without whether

Tags: conjunctions

Is it possible to use "or not" (clausal reduction) without whether or if?

> I will decide to do it or not. (without whether)

And this type of form

> I will decide to do it or do that.

Are these grammatical?

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is correct and understandable

> I will decide to do it or not.
>   We will decide to do it or not *(by tomorrow)*.

Your second sentence is also correct

> I will decide to do it or do that.

however, would be more idiomatic using "this"

> I will decide to do this or *(to)* do that *(before I leave)*.

"This" denotes *something* close, "that" denotes *something* farther away for contrast.

Also,

> I will decide to do it or not to do it.

is also correct.

Comment: then why do we use whether? Is it just redundant?

Comment: In your specific example "whether" might be considered unnecessary, however in "He needs you, whether he knows it or not" it is necessary. "Whether" functions as a flag that two alternatives are coming. "I will decide  to do it or not to do it", "I will decide whether to do it or not", "I will decide whether or not to do it" are all equivalent. "To be or not to be", "whether to be or not to be", "whether to be or not", "whether or not to be" are also all equivalent, but only the first one is famous, in those cases it's stylistic.